# How can one check his Canadian tax return has been successfully filed after leaving Canada?

Tags: taxes, canada

I lived in Canada last year.  I did a NETFILE system through an online tax company, and it came up with an error.  I tried again, and it still errored, but then returned me to the home page, where it says my return was 'printed and filed'.

This makes me uneasy, as at no point did they say 'yay, success' or anything along those lines.

Is there a way to check with CRA from outside the country to see if your return has been filed successfully? I'd hate to get stuck with a late filing.

Comment: I'll let people who used it answer but [My Account](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/ndvdls/myccnt/menu-eng.html) should let you do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Karlson mentioned, you can certainly check this through your CRA ["My Account for Individuals"](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/myaccount/).

If you haven't [registered for a CRA login](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/esrvc-srvce/tx/psssrvcs/pss_fq/cnd-eng.html) yet, you can either [create one](https://apps4.ams-sga.cra-arc.gc.ca/gol-ged/awsc/amss/enrol/start?prog=mima) (which means they mail you your PIN) or try signing in via one of their sign-in partners. They currently include:

- BMO Financial Group
- CHOICE REWARDS MasterCard
- Scotiabank
- Tangerine
- TD Bank Group

Comment: @MarkMayo: Make sure that you do not lose your copies of earlier tax returns during the move, since you need to input specific information from the tax return to get an account. Also, I was informed at the end that I needed to call them - maybe because I am no longer living there? - I've put that off for now, but will update once I do it if needed.